# Is there any way the bulk write operations in Mongodb can be used with GridFS?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

How can the bulk write operations in MongoDB 3.2 be used with GridFS? I am trying a batch upload with GridFS for around 100 files at a time. Is there any other option I should look into?
I'm a newbie and would appreciate any help. 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share some code of you?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Code for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no there is no bulk provided  for gridFS operation.

If you have a nice use case you could check [mongo jira](http://jira.mongodb.org) and submit a ticket for that.

Imho it is hard to imagine that this could be possible as imagine that bulk reads all files into memory .....